# I am a new user and I don't exactly understand your rules. Can someone tell me why this is off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold-questions

[image]

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [Phantasmagoric fractals .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273183/phantasmagoric-fractals)

How is this off topic?

Comment: "The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:

'This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.' "

Comment: A note to the down voters: To down vote this question is to suggest that it is a bad idea for new users to try to understand the site.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I didn't downvote this but I disagree to some extent. A) This topic has been discussed in meta quite often, and explanations are available (see the list of **Related** questions in the right margin). Learning the meta rule to look there is necessary for efficient use of the site. B) Many past "questions" around this theme were not clearly about learning how the site works. Rather they were covers for rants on "I oppose putting this on hold as off-topic". Item B) doesn't really apply here... hmm, may be putting rules in quotes makes it borderline :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen..."many past questions around this theme were not clearly about learning how the site works."That is exactly why I have asked this question. None of the older questions give actual clarity on what I m looking for. And as for "rules" making it look borderline, maybe now it is better :)

Comment: @MarkMcClure..I agree ...I don't see why this question should be down voted when I am just trying to understand this website.

Comment: "None of the older questions give actual clarity on what I m looking for." Then it seems mandatory to seriously explain what it is you are looking for, which must be very specific...

Comment: @Did.. What I mean is that I couldn't find a reason as to why my question was put on hold as off topic ....none of the earlier questions could help me with that because..let's say they did have a reason to be put on hold but my question didn't...

Comment: The question linked in the asker's post is now deleted, and very many users cannot access the linked question, and hence the question here becomes meaningless.

Comment: @amWhy Perhaps a screenshot of that question edited into this post would help?

Comment: You're perfectly capable of doing that too, @MarkMcClure.

Comment: @amWhy Thank you for the vote of confidence, but I don't particularly care about the issue. :)

Answer (score 9):

I voted to close that question because, as Jonas indicated in his comment, I felt that the question lacked context. More generally, I think that any question that *appears* to be just a statement of a problem from a classroom without any indication of where it came from should be closed for that reason. Quite a few folks active on the site hold a similar view, though there is some variation.

Here is some additional context that might help: What subject matter are you studying? Perhaps you're studying sequences and series, as they can be applied to problems of this nature. Or maybe you're studying Fractal Geometry specifically? Is it from a class? If so, what class? Perhaps you found it in a book that you're reading independently? All this information helps a respondent converse with you at the appropriate level. Also, lacking that context, the problem might appear to be a homework question that might be due for points. Many here don't want this site to be used for cheating on homework.

As I said, there is some variation on this theme. Some folks think it important that you type out any work that you've done. While I certainly think it can help to indicate what sorts of techniques you think should be applied, I also think this can be easily overdone. Indeed, too much work (which might or might not be correct) can easily muddle the question.

Finally, the title "Phantasmagoric fractals" is not at all descriptive and rather sophomoric. I clicked on it because I'm interested in fractal geometry but, based on the title, I wasn't surprised that I ultimately voted to close it.

Having said all that, I will point out that you did receive a pointer to a rather complete answer in the comments so I hope you found that helpful.

And thanks for asking this question! If you want more information on how to ask a good question, you can can check out this aptly named post:

- [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: My comment was an exact quote of what appeared on the page as the reason for closure.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes, that's pretty clear.